# Setting up wide monitor in XP

Tags: windows-xp, display, widescreen

I have windows XP on my second computer and a wide-screen monitor.

Text appears stretched with automatic settings.
How can I set it up properly?

Comment: thanks, good answers. all I needed is to scroll "screen resolution" around, dum#@$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the desktop (on any empty space, with nothing selected) and click properties. Next go to the Settings tab and you want to change "Screen resolution".

If your monitor has sent the correct information, you just want to move the slider up to maximum. If however Windows is reporting loads of settings (like in my screenshot), you want to just put it to the maximum that your monitor supports.

[image]

Comment: thanks I don't have options like you have 1 and 2 in that view

Comment: I have multiple screens set up, but I didn't know that VMware picks up on this :S

Answer (score 2):

Your resolution is most likely set to a 4.3 ratio setting (1024x768, 1280x1024, etc.)   You need to go into your monitor settings and set it to the proper widescreen resolution of your monitor (1680x1080, 1440x800, etc.)

Here is a good tutorial: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/personalize/resolution.mspx

[image: pic]

[image: pic2]

Answer (score 1):

`Right Click on desktop -> Properties -> The rightmost tab`

You'll have to forgive me if the details are wrong, it's been a few years since I last used an XP machine, but you probably want the resolution slider **all the way to the right**.