# widescreen resolution

Tags: windows-xp, display, widescreen

I have just changed my monitor from square shaped TFT monitor to widescreen lcd monitor but the problem I am getting is that the window screen is still square shaped it is not going wide. The window is displayed in middle and some screen is left on both side of monitor as shown in image[image].

Not sure how to adjust resolution to make window fit to whole screen.

Comment: Which operating system? You should change the output resolution.

Comment: @DanielAndersson: Windows XP and Intel motherboard. I am not sure but I think there is some BIOS settings for widescreen monitors

Comment: See the answers in this question: http://superuser.com/questions/72837/setting-up-wide-monitor-in-xp

Answer (score 0):

First, you would change the resolution from what it was, to one more suited to widescreen.  Right click on your desktop and choose properties... or enter the XP control panel and choose Display.  Either way, once the window comes up, choose the Settings tab, and you will see the resolution slider there.  Adjust it to a resolution that fits your new monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The screen resolutions available to you are dependent on the graphics card drivers.

Find out what graphic card or onboard graphics you have and install the latest drivers from the ATi, nVidia, Intel, Matrox, 3Dlabs, 3dfx..  website.

If you have a very old graphics card which does not have any newer drivers to install, you may be out of luck, but I think that is unlikely as I have found widescreen capable drivers for a twelve year old Matrox card quite recently.